# Express io has no method 'emit'

Tags: node.js, express

Im trying to emit event in routes.js on app.post and i got this errors : as no method 'emit'.

app.js :

```
app.io.route('setOnlineServer', function (req) {
Account.setOnline(req.user); 
});
```

routes.js

```
app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local'), function(req, res) {
    req.io.emit('setOnlineServer',req.user);
    res.redirect('/');
});
```

if i cant get users like this. Any idea to get authentified users?

Comment: may be way too late now, just check whether the "req" inherits from EventEmiiter..

Answer (score 0):

**Server (app.js)**

```
app = require('express.io')()
app.http().io()

// Broadcast the new visitor event on ready route.
app.io.route('ready', function(req) {
   req.io.broadcast('new visitor')
})

// Send client html.
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
res.sendfile(__dirname + '/client.html')
})

app.listen(7076)
```

**Client (client.html)**

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
io = io.connect()

// Send the ready event.
io.emit('ready')

// Listen for the new visitor event.
io.on('new visitor', function() {
    $('body').append('<p>New visitor, hooray! ' + new Date().toString() +'</p>')
})
</script>
```